# Laravel: как ограничить жадную загрузку (eager-loading)?

Tags: laravel

Пример из доков:

```
$users = User::with(['posts' => function($query)
{
    $query->where('title', 'like', '%первое%');
}])->get();
```

переделал под свой случай:

```
$ads = AD::with(['project' => function($query) use ($userId)
    {
        $query->where('active', '1')->where('user_id', $userId);
    }])
->get();
```

Вычисляю размер массива $ads  - выходит, что в массиве $ads все объявления, а не те, у которых 'active'='1' и 'user_id'=$userId.
Может кто подскажет, почему так может быть?

Comment: проверка по размеру массива - так себе, попробуйте вывести сам массив или сделайте хотя бы что-то вроде       
  `AD::with(['project' => function($query) use ($userId)
    {
        $query->where('active', '1')->where('user_id', $userId);
    }])
->where('active', '<>', 1)->orWhere('user_id', '<>', $userId)->get();`

Comment: Я попробовал работать с массивом (цикл foreach) - ограничение игнорируется.

Answer (score 2):

Поняла в чем подвох, в примере ограничение ставится на подгружаемые объекты `Posts`. Чтобы поставить ограничение на `AD`, то нужно написать так

```
$ads = AD::with(array('project'))
          ->where('active', , 1)
          ->orWhere('user_id', $userId)
          ->get();
```

или

```
$ads = AD::where('active', , 1)
          ->orWhere('user_id', $userId)
          ->get()
          ->load(array('project));
```

В первом случае `project` собираются для всех `AD` и затем идет фильтрация `AD`.
Во втором - сначала выбираем нужные `AD`, а затем - подгружаем к ним `project`. Практика показывает, то первый вариант быстрее , но второй по идее меньше грузит базу.