# Как сделать выборку только нужных полей из связанных таблиц в laravel 5

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Есть таблица goods и photos. Эти таблицы связаны между собой отношением один ко многим. То есть у одного good может быть много photo. Мне нужно сделать выборку всех good, сразу вместе с со всеми связанными photo. Также нужно выбрать значения не всех полей, а только нужных. И сделать это надо как в товарах, так и в фотографиях. Нужно, чтобы получился такой результат:

```
array:1 [
  0 => array:3 [
    "id" => 22997
    "name" => "Дроссельная заслонка, TOYOTA, -, 2AZ, Конт., (механич.)"
    "photos" => array:2 [
      0 => array:8 [
        "file_name_1920" => "1920_beab058e9f965a26ca597c3a2d5fad85.jpg"
      ]
      1 => array:8 [
        "id" => 14
        "file_name_1920" => "1920_ae27f461ea19678d07151993e6a30811.jpg""
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

Делаю выборку вот так:

```
$goods = Good::where('quantity', '>', 0)
        ->select(
            [
                'id',
                'name',
            ])
        ->with(['photos' => function($q)
        {
            $q->select('id', 'file_name_1920');
        }])
        ->orderBy('id', 'desk')->take(1)->get();

    dump($goods->toArray());
```

В результате получаю выборку без фотографий:

```
array:1 [
  0 => array:3 [
    "id" => 22997
    "name" => "Дроссельная заслонка, TOYOTA, -, 2AZ, Конт., (механич.)"
    "photos" => []
  ]
]
```

А если делаю выборку вот так:

```
$goods = Good::where('quantity', '>', 0)
        ->select(
            [
                'id',
                'name',
            ])
        ->with(['photos' => function($q)
        {
            //$q->select('id', 'file_name_1920');
        }])
        ->orderBy('id', 'desk')->take(1)->get();

    dump($goods->toArray());
```

То получаю все вместе с good получаю все photos, но вместе с ненужными полями:

```
array:1 [
  0 => array:3 [
    "id" => 22997
    "name" => "Дроссельная заслонка, TOYOTA, -, 2AZ, Конт., (механич.)"
    "photos" => array:2 [
      0 => array:8 [
        "id" => 13
        "sorting" => 0
        "good_id" => 22997
        "publish" => 1
        "file_name_1920" => "1920_beab058e9f965a26ca597c3a2d5fad85.jpg"
        "file_name_fit_640" => "fit_640_beab058e9f965a26ca597c3a2d5fad85.jpg"
        "created_at" => "2016-10-19 18:23:47"
        "updated_at" => "2016-10-19 18:23:47"
      ]
      1 => array:8 [
        "id" => 14
        "sorting" => 0
        "good_id" => 22997
        "publish" => 1
        "file_name_1920" => "1920_ae27f461ea19678d07151993e6a30811.jpg"
        "file_name_fit_640" => "fit_640_ae27f461ea19678d07151993e6a30811.jpg"
        "created_at" => "2016-10-19 18:23:49"
        "updated_at" => "2016-10-19 18:23:49"
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: не уверен, но может `->select(['table_name.id', '...'])`

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

Answer (score 1):

```
   ->with(['photos' => function($q)
    {
        $q->select('id', 'file_name_1920');
    }])
```

все правильно, просто поля по которым есть связь тоже должны присутствовать в выборке.

Answer (score 1):

На простом примере:
    $model = App\Model::find(34); // get model by id 34

```
// Если нужно массивом из основной модели
$array = $model->only('id', 'created_at', 'updated_at');

// Если нужно коллекцию но с нужными полями
$collection = $model->select('id', 'created_at', 'updated_at')->get();

// Если нужна связь с нужными ячейками
$relation = $model->relationModel->pluck('id');
```

Answer (score -1):

В одном ответе описывала как правильно использовать `with`: [Laravel: как ограничить жадную загрузку (eager-loading)?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/501695/laravel-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b6%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%ba%d1%83-eager-loading/501932#501932)

```
Model::with(array(bla-bla)) // with всегда в начале запроса
      ->where(bla-bla)
      ->get();
```

или

```
Model::where(bla-bla) 
      ->get()
      ->load(array(bla-bla)); // load применяется к коллекции (после get())
```

Возможно решит ваш вопрос